# Is there way to restrict an EditText to have only 4 line with 4 characters in them?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want an EditText such that it can have at most 4 lines, and each of these four line can only have 4 characters in them. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To restrict to 4 lines, use this in your EditText in xml:

```
android:maxLines=4
```

For that 4 character stuff, use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on EditText and check the String in the EditText. The nextline will be a character like "\n". Split the string on it, and do whatever you want.